# Mapping JSON Array to Spring Hibernate Database (H2)

Tags: json, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-mapping

Hi I'm trying to map a JSON to databse table in SprinBoot. 
This is my @Entity:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String tagline;
    private String first_brewed;
    @Column(length=700)
    private String description;
    private String image_url;
    private Long ibu;
    private String[] food_pairing;

    public User() {}
}
```

And JSON looks that:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Buzz",
        "tagline": "A Real Bitter Experience.",
        "first_brewed": "09/2007",
        "description": "A light, crisp and bitter IPA brewed with English and American hops. A small batch brewed only once.",
        "image_url": "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/keg.png",
        "ibu": 60,
        "food_pairing": [
            "Spicy chicken tikka masala",
            "Grilled chicken quesadilla",
            "Caramel toffee cake"
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to save this in to the H2 database.

Got only 1 column in the database with string of letters and numbers

My question is: How to change

> private String[] food_pairing;

to show all food_pairings as a separate columns in the database?

(If I have an object in JSON i can do that in the @Entity:

```
 @Embedded private Address address;
```

And then in other class:

```
@Embeddable public class Address {

 private String street;
 private String suite;

 }
```

And I have a automatic created columns in my database. I want to do the same but not with an object in JSON only with an Array of Strings in JSON.

Comment: I just don't understand your 2nd requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement, you want to persist this array `private String[] foodPairing;` in one column. If so, you can proceed like below :

```
public class User {
   ....
   @Transient 
   private String[] foodPairing;

   @Column(name="food_pairing")
   private String food_Pairing;
}
```

And before persisting your entity you can do this:

```
user.setFood_Paring(user.getFoodPairing().toString());
```

Then persist.

**EDIT:**

In case where you want each String in a one column, you can add 3 fields in your entity like this:

```
public class User {
   ....
   @Transient 
   private String[] foodPairing;

   @JsonIgnore
   @Column(name="food_pairing1")
   private String foodPairing1;

   @JsonIgnore
   @Column(name="food_pairing2")
   private String foodPairing2;

   @JsonIgnore
   @Column(name="food_pairing3")
   private String foodPairing3;
}
```

And when you persist:

```
user.setFoodParing1(user.getFoodPairing()[0]); //etc...
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need 3 columns that consist those 3 Strings in every column.

Comment: With this answer you have the idea. You can add as many columns as you want.

Comment: Yes but if I have an object in JSON i can do that in the @Entity:

/@Embedded
 private Address address;    


    And then in other class:
    
/@Embeddable
public class Address {

    private String street;
    private String suite; }
 
And I have a automatic created columns in my database. I want to do the same but not with a object in JSON only with a Array of strings.

Comment: It is not  your first requirement. Please edit your post and add these new requirements to make it more readable. Thanks

Comment: Many thanks my friend for your useful help. Compiled and works! :-)